# Jenkins connect to AWS instances dynamically

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have one question regarding Jenkins and connecting it to AWS instances.

I have a Jenkins server/ master node and I want it to connect to my AWS instances which are created & destroyed by an Auto Scale Group that they belong to.

I checked [ec2](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ec2/) and [ec2 fleet](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ec2-fleet/) plugins and even though they do what I need, to connect to each (currently) existing instance and create a slave for it, they both intervene with the creation/ termination of the instances as well as with my Auto Scale Group settings.

I simply want Jenkins to connect to my instances, do some CI/CD stuff there and that's about it.

I don't want Jenkins to either create or terminate any of my instances.

I can do that with static instances, by using their ip's but I can't  seem to find a way to do that with dynamically created instances.

Any ideas on how to work around that?

Thank you!

Comment: Check out the [Swarm PLugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/swarm/) - it enables nodes to join a nearby Jenkins server, so you can configure you instance with this plugin, and when they autoscale they will connect themself to the Jenkins server.

Comment: Thanks @NoamHelmer I will check it out!